# TypeError: jQuery(...).relCopy is not a function

Tags: php, jquery, yii, yii-extensions

Currently i am using **jqrelcopy** yii extension . I have a active textarea . i want to be add the relcopy function on that DOM element . in console i got this error 
      **TypeError: jQuery(...).relCopy is not a function**

**My view**

```
<div class="form-group" id="recop">
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'values',array('class'=>'col-sm-3 control-label')); ?>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
            <?php echo $form->textArea($model,'values',array('rows'=>6, 'cols'=>50)); ?>
            <?php echo $form->error($model,'values'); ?>
                    </div>
        </div>
    <?php 
               $this->widget('ext.jqrelcopy.JQRelcopy',
                     array(
                           'id' => 'recop',
                           //'removeText' => 'remove' //uncomment to add remove link
                           ));
              ?>
```

Nothing to be generated. Hope you help

**Generated HTML**

```
<html lang="en" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="no-touch"><head>
<!--<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>  -->
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <script src="sample/assets/f76af69a/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="sample/assets/da728c3f/js/jquery.relcopy.yii.1.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<title>NCTP-EMR - Create Master</title>

            <meta content="app, web app, responsive, admin dashboard, admin, flat, flat ui, ui kit, off screen nav" name="description">
            <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" name="viewport"> 
            <style>.file-input-wrapper { overflow: hidden; position: relative; cursor: pointer; z-index: 1; }.file-input-wrapper input[type=file], .file-input-wrapper input[type=file]:focus, .file-input-wrapper input[type=file]:hover { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; cursor: pointer; opacity: 0; filter: alpha(opacity=0); z-index: 99; outline: 0; }.file-input-name { margin-left: 8px; }</style><link href="sample/css/app.v1.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
            <link href="sample/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">     
            <link cache="false" href="sample/css/font.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <!--[if lt IE 9]> <script src="js/ie/respond.min.js" cache="false"></script>
            <script src="js/ie/html5.js" cache="false"></script>
            <script src="js/ie/fix.js" cache="false"></script> <![endif]-->
            <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">.jqstooltip { position: absolute;left: 0px;top: 0px;visibility: hidden;background: rgb(0, 0, 0) transparent;background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000);-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000)";color: white;font: 10px arial, san serif;text-align: left;white-space: nowrap;padding: 5px;border: 1px solid white;z-index: 10000;}.jqsfield { color: white;font: 10px arial, san serif;text-align: left;}</style><style id="GINGER_SOFTWARE_style" type="text/css">.GINGER_SOFTWARE_noMark { background : transparent; }  .GINGER_SOFTWARE_wrapper{ position: absolute; overflow: hidden; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px solid transparent } .GINGER_SOFTWARE_contour { position : absolute; margin: 0px; }  .GINGER_SOFTWARE_richText { margin : 0px; padding-bottom: 3px; border-width: 0px; border-color: transparent; display: block; color: transparent; -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent; overflow: hidden; white-space: pre-wrap;}  .GINGER_SOFTWARE_inputWrapper .GINGER_SOFTWARE_richText {position: absolute;}  .GINGER_SOFTWARE_canvas { display:none; background-repeat:no-repeat;}  .GINGER_SOFTWARE_control .GINGER_SOFTWARE_correct, .GINGER_SOFTWARE_control .GINGER_SOFTWARE_SpellingCorrect, .GINGER_SOFTWARE_control .GINGER_SOFTWARE_spelling, .GINGER_SOFTWARE_control .GINGER_SOFTWARE_mark {border-top-left-radius:2px; border-top-right-radius:2px; border-bottom-right-radius:2px; border-bottom-left-radius:2px;} .GINGER_SOFTWARE_control .GINGER_SOFTWARE_correct, .GINGER_SOFTWARE_control .GINGER_SOFTWARE_SpellingCorrect, .GINGER_SOFTWARE_control .GINGER_SOFTWARE_spelling, .GINGER_SOFTWARE_control .GINGER_SOFTWARE_mark {background-image:url(data:image/gif;base64,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)!important;} .GINGER_SOFTWARE_control .GINGER_SOFTWARE_correct.GINGER_SOFTWARE_synonym, .GINGER_SOFTWARE_control .GINGER_SOFTWARE_SpellingCorrect.GINGER_SOFTWARE_synonym, .GINGER_SOFTWARE_control .GINGER_SOFTWARE_spelling.GINGER_SOFTWARE_synonym, .GINGER_SOFTWARE_control .GINGER_SOFTWARE_mark.GINGER_SOFTWARE_synonym {background-image:url(data:image/gif;base64,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)!important;} .GINGER_SOFTWARE_control .GINGER_SOFTWARE_correct.GINGER_SOFTWARE_noSuggestion, .GINGER_SOFTWARE_control .GINGER_SOFTWARE_SpellingCorrect.GINGER_SOFTWARE_noSuggestion, .GINGER_SOFTWARE_control .GINGER_SOFTWARE_spelling.GINGER_SOFTWARE_noSuggestion, .GINGER_SOFTWARE_control .GINGER_SOFTWARE_mark.GINGER_SOFTWARE_noSuggestion {background-image:url(data:image/gif;base64,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)!important;} .GINGER_SOFTWARE_richText .GINGER_SOFTWARE_correct, .GINGER_SOFTWARE_richText .GINGER_SOFTWARE_SpellingCorrect, .GINGER_SOFTWARE_richText .GINGER_SOFTWARE_spelling, .GINGER_SOFTWARE_richText .GINGER_SOFTWARE_mark {position:relative; background-image:none!important;} .GINGER_SOFTWARE_richText .GINGER_SOFTWARE_markHighlightLeft { position : absolute; left:-2px; top:0px; bottom:0px; width:2px;} .GINGER_SOFTWARE_richText .GINGER_SOFTWARE_markHighlightRight { position : absolute; right:-2px; top:0px; bottom:0px; width:2px;} .GINGER_SOFTWARE_richText .GINGER_SOFTWARE_markHighlightTop { position : absolute; left:0px; right:0px; top:-2px; height:3px;} .GINGER_SOFTWARE_richText .GINGER_SOFTWARE_markHighlightBottom { position : absolute; left:0px; right:0px; bottom:-2px; height:3px;}</style></head>
<body ginger_software_stylesheet="true" spellcheck="false" ginger_software_doc="true">
<section class="hbox stretch"> <!-- .aside --> 
        <aside id="nav" class="bg-primary aside-sm">
     <section class="vbox">
        <header class="dker nav-bar">
                <a data-target="body" data-toggle="class:nav-off-screen" class="btn btn-link visible-xs"> <i class="icon-reorder"></i> </a> 
                <a data-toggle="fullscreen" class="nav-brand" href="#">Nctb-EMR</a>
                <a data-target=".nav-user" data-toggle="class:show" class="btn btn-link visible-xs"> <i class="icon-comment-alt"></i> </a>
        </header> 
        <footer class="footer bg-gradient hidden-xs"> 
            <a class="btn btn-sm btn-link m-r-n-xs pull-right" href="http://localhostsample/index.php?r=site/logout"> <i class="icon-off"></i> </a> 
            <a class="btn btn-sm btn-link m-l-n-sm" data-toggle="class:nav-vertical" href="#nav"> <i class="icon-reorder"></i> </a> 
        </footer>
    <section> 
    <div class="bg-success nav-user hidden-xs pos-rlt"> 
    <div class="nav-avatar pos-rlt"> 
    <a href="#" class="thumb-sm avatar animated rollIn" data-toggle="dropdown"> <img src="images/avatar.jpg" alt="" class=""> <span class="caret caret-white"></span> </a> <ul class="dropdown-menu m-t-sm animated fadeInLeft"> <span class="arrow top"></span> <li> 
    <a href="#">Settings</a> </li> <li> 
    <a href="profile.html">Profile</a> </li> <li> 
    <a href="#"> <span class="badge bg-danger pull-right">3</span> Notifications </a> </li> <li class="divider"></li> <li> 
    <a href="docs.html">Help</a> </li> <li> 
    <a href="signin.html">Logout</a> </li> </ul> 
    <div class="visible-xs m-t m-b"> 
    <a href="#" class="h3">John.Smith</a> <p><i class="icon-map-marker"></i> London, UK</p> </div> </div> 
    <div class="nav-msg"> 
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> <b class="badge badge-white count-n">2</b> </a> <section class="dropdown-menu m-l-sm pull-left animated fadeInRight"> 
    <div class="arrow left"></div> <section class="panel bg-white"> <header class="panel-heading"> <strong>You have <span class="count-n">2</span> notifications</strong> </header> 
    <div class="list-group"> 
    <a href="#" class="media list-group-item"> <span class="pull-left thumb-sm"> <img src="images/avatar.jpg" alt="John said" class="img-circle"> </span> <span class="media-body block m-b-none"> Use awesome animate.css<br> <small class="text-muted">28 Aug 13</small> </span> </a> 
    <a href="#" class="media list-group-item"> <span class="media-body block m-b-none"> 1.0 initial released<br> <small class="text-muted">27 Aug 13</small> </span> </a> </div> 
        <footer class="panel-footer text-sm"> 
            <a href="#" class="pull-right"><i class="icon-cog"></i></a> 
            <a href="#">See all the notifications</a> 
        </footer> 
    </section> 
    </section> 
    </div> 
    </div> 
        <nav class="nav-primary hidden-xs">
        <ul id="yw0" class="nav">
<li><a href="sample/index.php?r=site/index">Home</a></li>
</li>
<li><a href="sample/index.php?r=site/page&amp;view=about">About</a></li>
<li><a href="sample/index.php?r=site/contact">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="sample/index.php?r=site/logout">Logout (admin)</a></li>
</ul>        </nav>

</section></section></aside><!-- mainmenu -->     
    <section id="content"> 
                    <section class="vbox"> <header class="header bg-white b-b"><p>Create new field</p></header> 
                    <section class="scrollable wrapper"> 
                    <div class="row"> 
                    <div class="col-lg-12"> 
    <section class="panel">
    <div class="form panel-body">
<form method="post" action="sample/index.php?r=Master/create" id="fields-master-form" class="form-horizontal">
<!--    <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>-->


    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Master_field_name" class="col-sm-3 control-label required">Field Name <span class="required">*</span></label>                <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="text" id="Master_field_name" name="Master[field_name]" class="bg-focus form-control" maxlength="100" size="60">                        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Master_field_type" class="col-sm-3 control-label required">Field Type <span class="required">*</span></label>                <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="hidden" name="Master[field_type]" value="" id="ytMaster_field_type"><span id="Master_field_type"><input type="radio" name="Master[field_type]" value="Textbox" id="Master_field_type_0"> <label for="Master_field_type_0" style="display: inline; margin-right: 10px; font-weight: normal;">Textbox</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="Master[field_type]" value="Dropdown" id="Master_field_type_1"> <label for="Master_field_type_1" style="display: inline; margin-right: 10px; font-weight: normal;">Dropdown</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="Master[field_type]" value="Date" id="Master_field_type_2"> <label for="Master_field_type_2" style="display: inline; margin-right: 10px; font-weight: normal;">Date</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="Master[field_type]" value="TextArea" id="Master_field_type_3"> <label for="Master_field_type_3" style="display: inline; margin-right: 10px; font-weight: normal;">TextArea</label></span>                     </div>
    </div>
    <div id="recop" class="form-group">
        <label for="Master_values" class="col-sm-3 control-label required">Values <span class="required">*</span></label>                <div class="col-sm-4">
        <textarea id="Master_values" name="Master[values]" cols="50" rows="6"></textarea>                       </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row buttons">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" name="yt0"> </div>

</form>
</div><!-- form -->
                    </section>
                </div></div></section> 
                <a data-target="body" data-toggle="class:nav-off-screen" class="hide nav-off-screen-block" href="#"></a>
        </section> <!-- /.vbox --> 
</section>

<script src="sample/css/app.v1.js"></script><!--  Bootstrap   Sparkline Chart   App  -->
<script type="text/javascript">
/*&lt;![CDATA[*/
jQuery(function($) {
jQuery('#recop').relCopy([]);
});
/*]]&gt;*/
</script>





</section><iframe width="0" scrolling="no" height="0" frameborder="0" style="border: 0px solid; z-index: 2147483647; height: 0px; width: 0px; background-color: transparent;" src="about:blank" id="GINGER_SOFTWARE_contextMenuIFrame"></iframe><iframe width="0" scrolling="no" height="0" frameborder="0" style="border: 0px solid; position: absolute; z-index: 2147483647; height: 0px; width: 0px; background-color: transparent;" src="about:blank" id="GINGER_SOFTWARE_bubblesIFrame"></iframe><div style="display:none;" id="GingerWidgetInfo">{"version":"2.0.0.75","isExtension":true,"extensionName":"Firefox"}</div></body></html>
```

Comment: did you load the plugin after jquery and before calling it?

Comment: Yah yes i also try import that plugin by Yii::import. but the same error occur

Comment: @RyanBabu show us the final generated HTML

Comment: i just insert generated code on post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not find any mistakes in the plugin implementaion.

But in your HTML code, there are two jQuery plugin included. One is rendered by YII and another one is added by you from `//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.0.min.js`.

I hope the error is coming because of these two jQuery libraries, conflicting each other.

To solve the problem, just remove the first(rendered) jquery and keep your `jquery-1.11.0.min.js` before `jqrelcopy`  plugin.

Map the scripts to prevent the jQuery to render on the view. Check the `clientScript` part in `components`

```
'components' => array(
    'user' => array(
        .......
        ........
    ),
    'clientScript' => array(
        'scriptMap' => array(
            'jquery.js' => false,
        ),
    ),
```

Comment: Yes absolutely jquery conflicts make this problem. Thanks